# mCustomScrollbar won't scroll to the very bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm using this jQuery plugin called mCustomScrollbar and it works fine but I can't make it scroll to the page bottom completely. Here's my code, hope you can help me. Thanks.

```
     $(document).on('click','#comentar',function(e){
                        e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();


 $('.comentario').css({'background-image':'url(image/loading.gif)'});   

var comentario = $('.comentario').val();
var foto = $('.comentario').attr('id');


  var datosComentario='foto='+foto+'&comentario='+comentario;


    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "/includes/comentar.php",
        data: datosComentario,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function(){


                        },
        success: function(response){


      $('#comentarios_cont p').append(response);

      $('.comentario').val('').focus();

$("#comentarios_cont").mCustomScrollbar("update");
$("#comentarios_cont").mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo", "bottom");

      $('.comentario').css({'background-image':'none'}).val('');



        }

         });


});
```

It scrolls but not to the very bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a few minutes ago.
My problem was that a div inside mCSB_container had top and bottom margin. I removed them and now is okay, so check for this.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, it was a little complicated so i decided to change the plugin . It´s easy to use. The link is this. thanks again. http://nicescroll.areaaperta.com/